# In working out Auto White Balance, what to do if there are multiple sources of light?

Tags: white-balance, algorithms

I'm trying to research Auto White Balance Algorithms.
These algorithms are defined assuming only one source of light.

For example:

1.Grey world assumption ( this assumes that R, G and B average intensity are all the same)

2.Max-RGB (R,G and B's maximum values all assumed to be 255)

Specifically, I am wondering what to do if there is more than one source of  light in doing Auto White Balance in camera or Image signal Processing?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. What problem are you trying to solve? Are you trying to determine how to handle light sources with different temperatures in the same scene?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about signal processing and is not relevant to still photography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a research problem. There have been several papers presented at [SIGGRAPH](http://www.siggraph.org/) that offer differing solutions. For example:

[User-guided White Balance for Mixed Lighting Conditions](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/white_balance/) - has the user draw scribbles on the image showing the color of lights in a given area. The computer then adjusts the white balance accordingly.

[Light Mixture Estimation For Spatially Varying White Balance](http://slideplayer.com/slide/4915757/) - Attempts to figure out which areas are lit by yellowish lights vs blueish light and corrects them separately.

If you look through the references in both papers you'll find much more of interest.